# Customize action to be called in a controller from a form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a model Product that is both used by a general controller products_controller and another one used for administration purposes products_controller in an /admin folder.

Because I wanted to create a form that will be sent via AJAX and depending on whether the product is there or not it will alter between a :create and an :update, I've decided to create a 3rd method that takes care of that; called insert.

```
def insert
#blah
end
```

The form tag I'm using for updating is:

```
<%= form_for(product, :url => admin_product_url(product), :remote => true, :layout => true) do |f| %>
```

So my question is how can I customize the form tag in order to call the insert action I tried:

```
<%= form_for(product, :url => admin_product_url(product), :action => :insert, :remote => true, :layout => true) do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for(product, :url => insert_admin_product_url(product), :remote => true, :layout => true) do |f| %>
```

so far with no luck.

I hope someone could show me the way to go.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have to add below route in route file under the admin name space

```
match 'products/insert', :to =>'products#insert', :as => 'admin_products_insert'
```